# Removing single/multiple file from a git commit(s)

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and trying to clean up my branch where I intend to remove multiple files which were previously added.

The files that I intend to remove are having just additional white space which came after I removed some code. Basically without the white space this file is exactly the same as the base branch and so I don't want it to show up in my pull request.

The pull request I am talking about have multiple commits and is at a stage where I want to merge. I want to remove all files from this branch that are showing up just because of white space. I did try few things but nothing helped-

```
git checkout origin/<remote-branch> <filename>
git commit --amend
```

But this did not help, all I want to pick specific files from multiple commits that I made and remove them from my changes(branch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is 
Assuming a branch from master. Change command if not

git reset master

Git add -p

This will interactively go though the differences asking you one by one if you want them

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want to do is a rebase interactive `git rebase -i` where you will 'edit' all the commits you want to modify.

Should do the job...

Feel free to read more doc on rebase interactive.